# jQuery html() not updating with correct text

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a div

```
 <div id="box-loading-txt">txt</div>
```

and this jQuery code, that doesn't seem to work, 
div get updated with last HTML value "text B text B text B" even on first html() call

```js
var t = 200;
var d = 2000;

$('#box-loading-txt').delay(d).animate({
  'opacity': 0
}, t, function() {

  $('#box-loading-txt').html("text A text A text A").promise().done(function() {

    console.log("ok txt A");

    $('#box-loading-txt').animate({
      'opacity': 1
    }, t).delay(d);

    $('#box-loading-txt').animate({
      'opacity': 0
    }, t);
    $('#box-loading-txt').html("text B text B text B").promise().done(function() {
      console.log("ok txt B");
      $('#box-loading-txt').animate({
        'opacity': 1
      }, t).delay(d);
    });

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box-loading-txt">txt</div>
```

what I see is *"text B text B text B"* fading in, fading out but always with the same text, I never see *"text A text A text A"*

from console I can see "ok txt A", wait and then appear "ok txt B" but displayed text is always the last `html()` text

Comment: `html()` is not asynchronous so getting a `promise()` from it is redundant. What exactly is the behaviour you want to create?

Comment: I guess Op wants .. fadeOut .. change text to A ... FadeIn ... FadeOut ... change text to B ... fadeIn

Comment: i want to: fadeout div, change text, fadein, wait x,  fadeout div, change text, fadein, wait x 4/5 time. I have 4/5 text that the need to be display sequentially with some delay between one and another

Comment: try this one stackoverflow.com/questions/38228857/jquery-html-not-updating-with-correct-text/38229151#answer-38229151

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the delay doesn't affects html(), so while the queue of effects is delayed, the text is changed inmediately. You should probably use the complete option in animate() in order to change the text and do the next animation

Answer (score 1):

A prefer to use `triggers` in such cases.

Also 200 `delay` is to small for animation, I do not recommend to use delay less then 400-500

There is example

**[DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/ct3hqvyc/1/)**

```js
var t = 500;
var d = 2000;
var t1 = "text A text A text A";
var t2 = "text B text B text B";

$('#box-loading-txt').on('tiggerA', function() {

  $('#box-loading-txt').html(t1).promise().done(function() {
      console.log("ok txt A");
    $('#box-loading-txt').animate({
      'opacity': 1
    }, t, function() {
      $('#box-loading-txt').trigger('tiggerB');
    })

  });

})

$('#box-loading-txt').on('tiggerB', function() {
  $('#box-loading-txt').animate({
    'opacity': 0
  }, t, function() {

    $('#box-loading-txt').html(t2).promise().done(function() {
      console.log("ok txt B");
      $('#box-loading-txt').animate({
        'opacity': 1
      }, t).delay(d);
    });
  });

})


$('#box-loading-txt').delay(d).animate({
  'opacity': 0
}, t, function() {
  $('#box-loading-txt').trigger('tiggerA');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box-loading-txt">txt</div>
```

Comment: you guys are both correct but i guess i will flag Borgtex answer because more close to my code